# Determine if __getattr__ is method or attribute call

Tags: python, getattr

Is there any way to determine the difference between a method and an attribute call using __getattr__?

I.e. in:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if THIS_IS_A_METHOD_CALL:
            # Handle method call
            def method(**kwargs):
                return 'foo'
            return method
        else:
            # Handle attribute call
            return 'bar'

foo=Bar()
print(foo.test_method()) # foo
print(foo.test_attribute) # bar
```

The methods are not local so it's not possible to determine it using getattr/callable. I also understand that methods are attributes, and that there might not be a solution. Just hoping there is one.

Comment: You can tell if the object you're supposed to return is callable or not, but that doesn't mean it's going to be called... eg: would `list.reverse` be sufficient for "if THIS_IS_A_METHOD_CALL"... or is "list.reverse()" required for a method call

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot tell how an object is going to used in the `__getattr__` hook, at all. You can access methods without calling them, store them in a variable, and **later** call them, for example.

Return an object with a `__call__` method, it'll be invoked when called:

```
class CallableValue(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Lo, {} was called!".format(self.name)

class Bar(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return CallableValue(name)
```

but instances of this will not be the same thing as a string or a list at the same time.

Demo:

```
>>> class CallableValue(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         print "Lo, {} was called!".format(self.name)
... 
>>> class Bar(object):
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         return CallableValue(name)
... 
>>> b = Bar()
>>> something = b.test_method
>>> something
<__main__.CallableValue object at 0x10ac3c290>
>>> something()
Lo, test_method was called!
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, there is no reliable way - the issue is that a method *is* an attribute in Python - there is no distinction made. It just happens to be an attribute that is a bound method.

You can check if the attribute is a method, but there is no guarantee that means it will be called, e.g:

```
class Test:
    def test(self):
        ...

Test().test  # This accesses the method, but doesn't call it!
```

There is no way for the call accessing the function to know if it's going to be called when it is returned - that's a future event that hasn't yet been processed.

If you are willing to assume that a method being accessed is a method being called, you can determine that it is a method being accessed with a check like this:

```
hasattr(value, "__self__") and value.__self__ is self
```

Where `value` is the attribute you want to check to see if it is a method or some other attribute, and `self` is the instance you want to see if it's a method for.

If you need something to happen when it is called, you could use this moment to decorate the function.

An solid code example of this can be found [here](https://github.com/Lattyware/insightful/blob/master/insightful.py).

Comment: You can use `callable()` to determine if something is, well, callable. But that's not what the OP is looking for; they want to return a different result based on what the result will be used *for*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Callable doesn't mean it's a method. And as I say, that's impossible as Python doesn't know at request time whether the function is going to be called, so I gave the closest answer possible.

Comment: You can make *any* callable a method. And it doesn't have to be a method (descriptor binding) either here, not really.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to know whether an attribute is subsequently called from [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), which Martijn Pieters explains.

Although it does not determine whether an attribute is called, it is possible to know whether an attribute can be called with [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable). Another way is to use [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to keep track of the various objects, or make a list of attribute names.

```
class Foo(object):
    bar_attribute = 'callable'

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        instanceOrValue = getattr(self, "bar_%s" %name)

        if callable(instanceOrValue):
            # Handle object that can be called
            def wrap(**kwargs):
                return "is %s" %instanceOrValue(**kwargs)
            return wrap

        # Handle object that can not be called
        return 'not %s' %instanceOrValue

    def bar_method(self, **kwargs):
        return 'callable';
    

foo=Foo()
print(foo.method()) # is callable
print(foo.attribute) # not callable
```

[`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) can only keep track of certain things, but it can be the right solution in many situations because change calling ([`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__)) has an impact on calling in all situations and not only when the Foo class is used.

[Difference between calling a method and accessing an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000450/difference-between-calling-a-method-and-accessing-an-attribute)

[What is a "callable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable)

[Python __call__ special method practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824881/python-call-special-method-practical-example)