# what's the difference between property and class method?

Tags: python, django, django-models

What's the difference between a class *property* and a class *method*? As I understand it, *property* is calculated when an object is created. And *method* makes calculations when I call it.

Is there any other difference than that?

For example, I have a `property` in my `class Product()`:

```
@property
    def total_ammount_in_store(self):
        consignments = self.product.package.consignments
        total_ammount = 0
        for consignment in consignments:
            total_ammount += consignment.package_ammount
```

When I render some page, I pass some products. For example:
`{'products':Product.objects.filter(expiration_data < datetime.now())`

I don't need to calculate `total_ammount_in_store` every time I get an instance of `Product`. What if I just need to calculate it when I call it in a template: {{product.total_ammount_in_store}}? Is it possible?

Is *method* also calculated when the object is created?

Comment: it is rather class attribute than class method http://stackoverflow.com/a/17000468/3033586

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The property is called each time you access `product.total_ammount_in_store`, not at the time when the product is created.

Therefore including `{{ product.total_ammount_in_store }}` in your template will do the right thing.

By using the property decorator, you can access `product.total_ammount_in_store` instead of `product.total_ammount_in_store()` if it was an instance method. In the Django template language, this difference is not so apparent, because Django will call the method automatically in the template.

Don't confuse an instance method with a [class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod), which is quite different. A class method belongs to your class `Product`, not an individual instance `product`. You don't have access to instance variables e.g. `self.package` when you call a class method.

Comment: When I try to debug my project, I noticed that when I pass in `render` my products, `total_ammount_in_store` property is executed too.

Comment: I don't use my property in my template. But that property is executed.

Comment: @Andrew This sounds like you actually are using it in the template or in the view. Can you show us the code?

Comment: Raise an exception inside the property. The traceback should show you the code that is accessing the property.

Comment: @Andrew, use Alasdair's idea with the exception.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, I found it. In template I use `is_available` property that is based on `total_amount_in_store`. Ty

Comment: @Alasdair But what's the difference if `total_ammount_in_store` is a `property` or a class method? It will return result in both cases, when I access it `{{product.total_ammount_in_store}}`

Comment: You are right, that there is no difference between accessing a property or instance method in the Django template. I've updated my answer to try to make it clearer.

Comment: @Andrew, please beware of the difference between class method and instance method.

Answer (score 3):

The `@property` decorator can be used to implement a getter for your class' instance variable (in your case it would be `self.total_ammount_in_store`). Every time you call `some_product.total_ammount_in_store`, the decorated method is executed. It wouldn't make sense to execute it only when a new object is created - you want to get current amount in store, don't you?
More reading on `@property` is in Python documentation (it's a Python's construct, not Django's):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

As for class methods, they are something completely different. As the name suggests, they're tied to classes, not instances. Therefore, no instance is needed to call a class method, but also you can't use any instance variables in class methods (because they are tied to a particular instance).

To the Django related part of your question...

If you include `{{ some_product.total_ammount_in_store }}` in your template, then every time the page is displayed, the total amount in store is obtained from the `some_product` instance. Which means that the decorated `total_ammount_in_store` getter is called.

If for example the total amount in store isn't changed during the product's life, you can calculate the amount in `__init__` method and then only return the value. If the total amount can change you can do it as well but you will need to ensure that the amount is re-calculated every time it should be changed - e.g. by calling a method. Like this:

```
class Product(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        # other initialization
        # ...
        self.recalculate_amount()

    def recalculate_amount(self):
        consignments = self.product.package.consignments
        self._total_amount = 0
        for consignment in consignments:
            self._total_amount += consignment.package_amount

    @property
    def total_amount(self):
        """Get the current total amount in store."""
        return self._total_amount
```

Then the getter is still called every time you call `some_product.total_ammount_in_store` (e.g. in your Django template), but it will not calculate the amount every time - it will use the stored amount instead.

Comment: A question about last part of your answer: for example, when I write in view next code: `Product.objects.filter(some_condition)`, it will recalculate total amount for every instance?

Comment: @Andrew This actually depends on what `some_condition` is. If you use something like `Product.objects.filter(total_amount < 100)` then with my code example, it won't recalculate every time. It will call the `total_amount()` method for every `Product` instance, but the method will only return the stored number. The stored number will be recalculated only if you call the `recalculate_amount()` method. Which might be what you want and also might be something else than you actually want.

Comment: Ok, I try to put another question: `__init__ `method is called only when object is created, or even when we call `Product.objects.filter(total_amount < 100)` ?

Comment: @Andrew Only when a new object is created. For more information read the method's documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__

Comment: so, when I access `product.total_amount` property as in your code, it can return old value of `total_amount`, because I didn't call `recalculate_amount` method before?

Comment: @Andrew, yes. It will only be updated by the `recalculate_amount` method. Actually you can add an alternative way to update the amount (for example add another method `ship(self, how_many)` that will subtract `how_many` from `self._total_amount` etc.), but the total amount won't be recalculated every time you get its value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76663/discussion-between-andrew-and-geckon).