# In python I tried to find max value in a list without max() in a list but it shows "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findmax' "

Tags: python, list, function, loops, max

```
a=int(input('Enter number of values:'))

l=[]

for i in range(0,a):
    b=input('*Enter the value:')
    l.append(b)

print(l)

def findmax():
    j=0
    for i in range(0,a):
        k=j+1
        if(l[j]>l[k]):
            print (l[j]," is the max value")
        else:
            j=j+1

l.findmax()
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of input/output?

Answer (score 0):

`findmax` is not an attribute of a list, it is a function. You have to call the function by writing `findmax()`, however a good practice would be to define your function for any list and not just for your list `l`. The program also has issues when you do `if(l[j]>l[k]):` because you are out of range.

Here is a piece of code that works as intended I believe.

```
def findmax(myList):
    myMax = myList[0]
    for i in myList:
        if i > myMax:
            myMax = i
    return myMax        

l = [1,2,3,4]
print(findmax(l))
```

This is worth a read :
[Difference between methods and attributes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312470/difference-between-methods-and-attributes-in-python)